# Synchronous HTTP POST calls and storing the response data in every call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

Hi I need to implement a logic where I need to make a chain of POST calls to get the data from services. These calls need to be handled synchronously. Here is a sample of what I need:

firstPOSTcall -> wait for response(store the response in an array) -> secondPOSTcall -> wait for response(store the response in an array) ->third POST call -> wait for response(store the response in an array).

I need to do this in Angular. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you work with *Promises*, it's designed for this kind of situation. http://www.tivix.com/blog/making-promises-in-a-synchronous-manner/

Comment: The only way you can achieve this is through Promises, as @Booster2ooo suggested. Every other POST call should be placed into success callback of previous.